# What do I add to the D20 roll of a Concentration Check?

Tags: dnd-5e, concentration

So I understand the the basics of a Concentration check the only thing that I don't understand is what, if anything, do you add to the D20 roll? I can't find anything in the book so any assistance is helpfull.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Technically there's no such thing as a *"concentration check"* in 5e.

A "concentration check" is actually a *constitution saving throw*.

From page 203-204 of the PHB:

> **Taking damage.** Whenever you take damage while you are concentrating on a spell, you must make a **Constitution saving throw to maintain your concentration** [...]
>
> The DM might also decide that certain environmental phenomena, such as a wave crashing over you while you're on a storm-tossed ship, require you to succeed on a DC 10 **Constitution saving throw to maintain concentration on a spell.**

As such, you would add your constitution modifier and proficiency bonus, if proficient in con saves, to the D20 roll.